# How to specify method to call based on route parameter?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-httpclient

I have a `ProfileComponent` in my Angular app, as well as 2 JSON files - `employees.json` &  `managers.json`

Previously, I used the following check in `profile.component.ts`:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
        const roleId = +params.get('role');
        const empId = +params.get('id');
        if (empId) {
            if (roleId === 1) {
                this.getEmployee(empId);
            } else if (roleId === 2) {
            this.getManager(empId);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

HTML:

```
<td (click)="viewEmployeeProfile(1, employee.id)">{{employee.fullName}}</td>
<td (click)="viewEmployeeProfile(2, manager.id)">{{manager.fullName}}</td>
```

If roleId = 1, display data from `employees.json`, if roleId = 2 then display data from `managers.json`

Here are my methods:

```
getEmployee(id: number) {
    this.employeeService.getEmployee(id).subscribe(
        (employee: IEmployee) => this.displayEmployee(employee),
        (err: any) => console.log(err)
    );
}

getManager(id: number) {
    this.managerService.getManager(id).subscribe(
        (manager: IManager) => this.displayManager(manager),
        (err: any) => console.log(err)
    );
}
```

And here are the methods in my services:

`Employee Service`

```
baseUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/employees';

getEmployee(id: number): Observable<IEmployee> {
    return this.httpClient.get<IEmployee>(`${this.baseUrl}/${id}`)
        .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
}
```

`Manager Service`

```
baseUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/managers';

getManager(id: number): Observable<IManager> {
     return this.httpClient.get<IManager>(`${this.baseUrl}/${id}`)
        .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
}
```

This was working before, but I have since decided to add `canActivate()` guard to stop user's navigating to the Profile component with an invalid ID.

Here is my route:

```
{
    path: 'profile/:role/:id', component: ProfileComponent,
    canActivate: [RequireEmployeeProfileGuardGuard]
}
```

And here is what I have in my guard:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> {
return this.employeeService.getEmployee(+route.paramMap.get('id')).pipe(
catchError(() => of(false)),
map(employee => !!employee || this.router.parseUrl('page-not-found'))
);
}
```

Now, when I search for an Employee, the app works fine because it is searching `employees.json`.
But, if I choose to display a Manager, it fails because it is searching `employees.json` for the Manager's ID.

Can someone please point out what changes I need to make so that my code searches the correct file?

Comment: You guard search only in `employees.json` is it normal?

Comment: Hi @youri, above I have some `<td>` tags. If the user clicks the first one, 1 is passed to the route as the `role`. If the user clicks the second one, 2 is passed to the route. Previously, this told my code which JSON to read

Comment: Your employee service and manager service both use the same baseUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/managers'; Is this intended?

Comment: @SeverinKlug Hi, sorry that's a typo. I'll update now

Answer (score 1):

You can have your `canActivate` method like what you were doing in the component like this:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> {

    const roleId = +route.paramMap.get('role');
    const empId = +route.paramMap.get('id');

    if(roleId === 1) {
        //employee
        return this.employeeService.getEmployee(empId)
                   .pipe(
                        map(employee => {
                            if(employee) {
                                return true;
                            } else {
                                this.router.parseUrl('page-not-found');
                                return false;
                            }
                        })
                    );

    } else if(roleId === 2) {
        //manager
        return this.managerService.getManager(empId)
                    .pipe(
                        map(manager => {
                            if(manager) {
                                return true;
                            } else {
                                this.router.parseUrl('page-not-found');
                                return false;
                            }
                        })
                    );
    } else {
        //do not pass the guard
        of(false);
    }
}
```

To avoid code duplication you can have a higher order function like this:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> {

    const roleId = +route.paramMap.get('role');
    const empId = +route.paramMap.get('id');
    const myMap = map(emp => {
        if(emp) {
            return true;
        } else {
            this.router.parseUrl('page-not-found');
            return false;
        }
    })
    if(roleId === 1) {

        return this.employeeService.getEmployee(empId)
                   .pipe(
                        myMap
                    );

    } else if(roleId === 2) {
        return this.managerService.getManager(empId)
                    .pipe(
                        myMap
                    );
    } else {
        //do not pass the guard
        of(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: When I use your first solution, it works as expected. But if I use the "reusable" solution, I'm getting the following warning over the `myMap` code: _unused expression, expected an assignment or function call (no-unused-expression)_

Comment: @user9847788 See my updated answer. I did a typo. It should be `const myMap = map(....`